# git push with one username, pull with another

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull

I'm using Git to deploy code onto a server with multiple branches for live and staging setups. I'd like to build a simple web interface for pulling without password, but for security reasons, I'd like to push only from command line with a password secured private key. I have set up two usernames, one of them read-only.

Is there a way to configure the clones repository on the server this way? I've seen the `pushurl` and `remote.url` entries in the configuration file, but can't see how I would specify a user for them.

Answer (score 1):

A more robust way of configuring read/write access would be to install on the server side an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/auth.html) like **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/master-toc.html)**.

Then you can setup your 2 usernames in order for one to clone only, the other to push (to the full repo or only to certain branches).